# Datetime fields in json

Tags: java, json, postgresql, jackson

How do we store postgres datetime objects in java pojo classes for json objects? I am trying to sort them and want to check if I should be comparing datetime or strings? Date compareTo doesn't work but strings comparTo works fine for datetime objects

private Date fieldA; 
private Date fieldB;

fieldA.compareTo(fieldB);

Comment: What do you mean by `Date compareTo` doesn't work?  It always seems to work for me.  Have you got an example of two dates for which it gives an incorrect result?

Comment: I don't have example with me right now but it is something like (1995-02-23T12:02:56).compareTo(1992-01-01T01:12:23) won't work if they are stored as Date objects but they will work if they are stored as strings. Also I think in pojo class for json they should be stored as strings as there is no concept of Date objects in json?

Comment: What type is the column you're storing dates in? `TIMESTAMPTZ(3)` will lead to fewer surprises.

Comment: @JEE_program I find that extremely difficult to believe.  Is there any possibility you have made a mistake of some kind?

Comment: No mistake. Try it. Also I think it should be stored as string types in pojo class for json?

Comment: Try what? Add some code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: What does Postgres or JSON has to do with how we store datetime in Java POJOs? Just use whatever type best suits your need in Java. Nowadays most people tend to prefer `java.time` types.

Comment: You have a date/time value, store them as such - when needed, format it as String, cause json is text based

Comment: Well, I tried it.  It works fine for me.  Would you like to show us the code in which you compare 1995-02-23T12:02:56 to 1992-01-01T01:12:23 so someone can see what your mistake is?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

> How do we store [postgres datetime objects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) in java pojo classes for json objects?

It depends.

- For a Postgres column of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, use the [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class.
- For a Postgres column of `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, use the [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class.

As for JSON, there are no JSON data types for date-time values. Generate strings in standard ISO 8601 format.

> I am trying to sort them

The *java.time* classes know how to sort themselves, implementing the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.

> if I should be comparing datetime or strings?

Always use smart objects, not dumb strings. That is why you have [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) technology and [JDBC drivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver).

> Date compareTo doesn't work

Never use the `java.util.Date` class. Never use the `java.sql.Date` class. Use only *java.time* classes.

> strings comparTo works fine for datetime objects

Nope. Date-time strings can come in all kinds of formats, using all kinds of human languages and cultural norms, with various time zones or offsets-from-UTC applied. Strings are *not* appropriate for sorting date-time values. Use smart *java.time* objects, not dumb strings.

Or do your sorting on the database side, where Postgres is optimized for such chores.

> private Date fieldA; private Date fieldB;

Make that:

```
private Instant fieldA, fieldB ;
…
boolean isAEarlier = fieldA.isBefore( fieldB ) ;
boolean isAtheSame = fieldA.equals( fieldB ) ;  // Note that some other java.time classes have `isEqual` method as well as `equals` method.
boolean isALater = fieldA.isAfter( fieldB ) ;
boolean isAEqualToOrLaterThan = ( ! fieldA.isBefore( fieldB ) ) ;  // "Is equal to or later than" is a common use-case. "Not before" is a logical shortcut with the same effect.
```

## java.time

The `Date` class is now legacy, part of the terribly troublesome old date-time classes that were supplanted by the *java.time* classes years ago. Never use `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and such.

Your Question is a duplicate of many others, so I'll be brief here. Search Stack Overflow to learn more.

### Attached to the timeline

For the database column type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` defined in the SQL standard and used in Postgres, that represents a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

In [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL), this type has a resolution of [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) and is ***always* in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)**. Any inputs with an indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC are adjusted into UTC, and the zone/offset then discarded. So the type is a bit of a misnomer, as the original zone/offset is forgotten and the stored value is always in UTC. Other databases may vary in this behavior, so beware, as the SQL spec barely touches on the subject of date-time.

Beware that when using tools other than [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity), your tool may be injecting a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) after retrieving the stored UTC value; this can be quite misleading and confusing to a novice (and is an unfortunate design decision in my opinion).

In Java, generally best to work in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). As a programmer, learn to think, store, and exchange moments as UTC. Generally, use the `Instant` class for this. For defining member variables in your classes, `Instant` is your go-to class.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC, with a resolution as fine as nanoseconds.
```

You may want to truncate any [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) to microseconds to match retrieved values from Postgres. Specify resolution with [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MICROS ) ;
```

For presentation to the user in their desired/expected time zone, assign a [`ZonedId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

To get back to UTC, extract a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

To generate localized text representing the value of the `ZonedDateTime` object, use `DateTimeFormatter`. Search Stack Overflow for much more info.

### Not attached to the timeline

The database type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. As such it does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline, and is *not* what you likely want in a business app except when:

- Scheduling appointments out into the future.
- Representing the concept of a date and time to *every* zone or *any* zone, not a particular zone.

In Postgres, any zone or offset accompanying input is ignored. The date and the time-of-day are stored as-is with no adjustment.

The matching type in Java is [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

The “Local” in this class name does **not** mean “a particular locality”. Just the opposite! It means *every* locality, or *any* locality, but not a particular locality. If you do not understand this, do some study, read the class doc, and search Stack Overflow.

## Database

Use smart objects rather than dumb strings to exchange date-time values with your database.

As of [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221), you can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database. Never use `java.sql.Timestamp`, `java.sql.Date`, and `java.sql.Time`.

Storage.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

## JSON

The [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) spec defines very few data types, and none of them are date-time related. You are on your own there. Ditto for [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML).

### ISO 8601

When serializing date-time values as text, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. These are designed to be practical and useful, and to avoid ambiguities. They are designed to be easy to parse by machine, while also being easy to read by humans across cultures.

The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating date-time strings. Just call `parse` and `toString` on the various classes.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2018-01-23T01:23:45.123456Z" ) ;

String output = instant.toString() ;
```

The ISO 8601 format for a moment happen to be similar to the usual SQL format except that in SQL uses a SPACE in the middle rather than a `T`. That fact is largely irrelevant as you should be using objects rather than strings between Java and your database, as mentioned above.

## Half-Open

Related to the topic of comparing… When working with spans of time, learn to consistently use the Half-Open approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. Search Stack Overflow to learn more.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `java.time.LocalDateTime` class.  This is the new (Java 8) class for representing a date and time without any specific time zone or offset.

In other words, you can think of it as holding a year, month, day, hour, minute, second and millisecond.  But because there's no time zone or offset specified, it doesn't actually correspond to a particular `Instant` - that is, a particular moment in time.

It seems to me that of all the Java 8 date/time related classes, this is the one that's closest in intent to what you'd store in a database's DateTime field.

Further reading: Basil Bourque's answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39628885)

Comment: Thanks. I have used java.sql Timestamp and it works fine. I couldn't see LocalDatetime supported by Json Jackson library.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I have used java.sql Timestamp and it works fine. I couldn't see LocalDatetime supported by Json Jackson library. – JEE_program Jul 3 at 21:47